# Inject javascript class with variables and functions into WebView in iOS 14.0. - 14.4

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to inject some simple javascript in a WKWebview and it's working fine for iOS 14.5 and iOS 15+.

It's not working for iOS 14.0 - 14.4. Seems like the javascript is wrong for those specific iOS versions.

Is there any other way that I could write this javascript code?

Relevant code snippets:

```swift
     enum Constants {
        static let loginMessageHandler = "loginMessageHandler"

        static let js = """
        class JavascriptClass {

            static openLogin () {
                if (window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers && window.webkit.messageHandlers.loginMessageHandler) {
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.loginMessageHandler.postMessage({
                        "message": "Login"
                    });
                }
            }
            static age;
            static height;

            static getInfo() {
                if (this.age && this.height) {
                    return `{\"age\": \"${this.age}\", \"height\": \"${this.height}\"}`;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        """
    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true

        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: Constants.loginMessageHandler)

        let script = WKUserScript(source: Constants.js, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

        let url = URL(string: [some url string])!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

extension JSWebviewViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print(message.body)

        if message.name == Constants.loginMessageHandler {
            didTapOpenLoginButton()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was solved by **removing the static class field declarations** from the javascript code, as it seems that for iOS versions 14.0 - 14.4 it wasn't supported yet.

```
static let js = """
    class JavascriptClass {
        static openLogin () {
            if (window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers && window.webkit.messageHandlers.loginMessageHandler) {
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.loginMessageHandler.postMessage({
                    "message": "Login"
                });
            }
        }

        static getInfo() {
            if (this.age && this.height) {
                return `{\"age\": \"${this.age}\", \"height\": \"${this.height}\"}`;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    """
```